# Calculate the determinant when the sum of odd rows $=$ the sum of even rows

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have came across this interesting question in linear algebra and I couldn't know for sure the answer.

> Given a matrix $A \in M_{n \times k} (\mathbb F)$, The sum of odd rows of $A$ $=$ the sum of even rows of A (regarding indexes, that is.) What is $det(A)$?

At first glance, I immediately said that $det(A) = 0$ because if we add all rows $a_i$ such that $i$ is even to $a_2$ and if we add all rows $a_i$ such that $i$ is odd to $a_1$ then we get two rows that are the same. But then I came to think about it, what does it even mean "The sum of odd indexed rows"? Is it a vector? A number? It must be a vector.
But then, what does it mean the sum of a bunch of vectors?

Comment: One of the basic properties of vectors (of the same dimension, over the same field) is that you can add them. Two vectors are equal just when all their components are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To row 2 add row 4, then add row 6, then add row 8, $\ldots$. In the end row 2 will be a row that will equal the sum of all the even rows.  If you want you can think of it as a vector equalling the sum of a bunch of vectors, but what's important here is it's a row of a matrix.

Repeat with row 1 and the odd rows, and row 1 will agree with row 2.

More details added:  Let $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&3&3&2\\5&6&5&6\\4&5&5&8\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.  Then the first and third rows add up to $(\begin{smallmatrix}6&8&8&10\end{smallmatrix})$, as do the second and fourth rows.

Comment: That's exactly my question. How to I think of it? "Sum of rows"? would that mean that every index in the first row is equal to every equalivant index in the second row?

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the even rows by -1 and add the result to the odd rows then you obtain a row of 0s. Thus the rows are linearly dependent, which implies that the determinant is 0.